# pipe into a curses program

Tags: terminal, pipe, ncurses

The library ncurses provides an interactive user interface. However, I was wondering what would happen if you pipe something into the program. So i tried like this:

```
# echo foo | my_curses_prog
```

It seems there is always input pending on stdin but `getch` cannot read anything. So what's happening under the hood?

---

Updated test program:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
    WINDOW *win = initscr();
    nodelay(win, 0);
    refresh();
    FILE *fp = fopen("my_curses_prog.log", "w");
    while (1) {
        int ch = getch();
        fprintf(fp, "%d\n", ch);
        fflush(fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am currently writing an application with ncurses and I want to pipe input into it and I am hitting the same error. It continuously returns ERR, does not halt, I cannot clear the input buffer with `flushinp()` and it doesn't even accept any other inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

curses applications can be initialized using **`initscr`** or **`newterm`**.  The former reads *stdin* only; the latter can be told to use a different input.  If you want to have a curses application reading from a pipe, you would use **`newterm`** ([dialog](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) does this).

curses expects its input to be a ***terminal***.  A pipe is never going to act like a terminal, since it is buffered, cannot be changed to *raw mode* using the [standard terminal I/O](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/basedefs/termios.h.html) calls.  Since its input is *buffered*, you don't see much useful happening with **`getch`** until it is able to read the whole buffer (lots of characters, or until a newline, depending on how you're testing).

Comment: OK my bad. I'm only using stdin so I think `initscr` should work. Yeah, it actually gets those input characters when fd0 is a pipe. But the problem with a pipe is that when `getch` hits EOF, it keeps returning -1 instead of blocking (even if `nodelay` is false). So there is no input pending but EOF keeps giving `getch` ERR. I think this is probably due to some internal `select` call in ncurses which reports a fd as ready on EOF. Well, I thought I could test my curses application by piping in keystrokes, now there's a caveat.